# How to change the current selected line background in Intelij IDEA inputing suggestion popup?

Tags: intellij-idea, themes

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, when inputing, it will display a suggestion popup. However, the selected line's background is not obvious enough, how to change it?

It should be set in "Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General". I have tried a lot to modify the settings, but can't find the correct one. **Please tell me which one is it**.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Color for completion popup are hardcoded and could be changed only via custom color scheme. Please vote for the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143131/Completion-colors-differ-from-other-UI-elements